# How can I add Facebook SDK to Android project on Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, sdk

I exactly followed the direction of Android Guide for how to add FB SDK on Android. I always get errors like in pictures. How can I figure it out?

Here is how to view of project:

[image]

Errors:

[image]

Comment: and the errors are ?

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/152oroo.jpg

Comment: are you sure you are using the "android" sdk ?

Comment: Exactly, I took it from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: what is your jdk version  ?

Comment: jdk 1.8.0.25 @MuhannadFakhouri

Comment: hmm 
sounds interesting ... check Project settings for Facebook

Comment: Already checked and everything is good but It still doesen't work.

Comment: it most be related with your compiler's java version , How did you imported this module

Comment: I thought same thing and installed last version of Eclipse. I imported with this way: Imported>Existing Android Code Into Workspace and I did it "Is library"

Comment: i think you must import Google Play Services library first,before trying any other things.

Comment: I did import Google Play Services library but still doesn't work :( @VarunMadhvani

Comment: I would focus first on including only the Facebook Project and not the Samples. If for any reason importing the SDK project into Eclipse fails, you will get stuck with a million errors. Then I would try to post here a more detailed look into what the errors from importing that one are. Can you do that and update your description with your findings?

Comment: I did include just SDK. Evrything is so good till click to build project. After click I got million errors. If I don't build it, I can't implement to my project cuz project needs facebook.jar from sdk library project. @corvuszero